# Unable to POST metadata and multipart at the same time. Getting a 400 Bad request

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I'm trying to upload a file and add some JSON data in query params (Code below) from my UWP app. But, I'm getting a 400 bad request. Not sure what I'm missing here. But, I'm able to perform the same from postman and get a 200 OK.

Can anyone help?

```
        string apiUrl = BuildUrl(url, apiContext);

        // req params which has the json string as key value pair and few other request parameters
        Uri uri = BuildUriWithQueryParams(apiUrl, reqParams);

        HttpRequestMessage reqMsg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri);

        // File upload
        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpMultipartFormDataContent formDataContent = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();
            foreach (StorageFile storageFile in files)
            {
                var inputStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
                HttpStreamContent httpStreamContent = new HttpStreamContent(inputStream);
                formDataContent.Add(httpStreamContent, "doc", storageFile.Name);
            }
            reqMsg.Content = formDataContent;
        }
        var response = await HttpClient.SendRequestAsync(reqMsg);//.AsTask(cts.Token);
```

Comment: You can close this case by mark your own answer. Which will be clear to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the JSON req parameters from the query params and adding to HttpStringContent resolved the issue for me. Mentioned below the changes needed.

```
 string apiUrl = BuildUrl(url, apiContext);

        // req params which has the json string as key value pair and few other request parameters
//    Uri uri = BuildUriWithQueryParams(apiUrl, reqParams);
      UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(apiUrl);

        HttpRequestMessage reqMsg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uriBuilder .Uri);

        HttpMultipartFormDataContent formDataContent = new HttpMultipartFormDataContent();

        // File upload
        if (files != null && files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (StorageFile storageFile in files)
            {
                var inputStream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
                HttpStreamContent httpStreamContent = new HttpStreamContent(inputStream);
                formDataContent.Add(httpStreamContent, "doc", storageFile.Name);
            }
        }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair in reqParams)
                formDataContent.Add(new HttpStringContent(keyValuePair.Value), keyValuePair.Key);
            reqMsg.Content = formDataContent;

        var response = await HttpClient.SendRequestAsync(reqMsg);//.AsTask(cts.Token);
```